# Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vm2/lib/resolver-compat.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in \node_modules\vm2\lib'
Error from chokidar (E:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'E:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (E:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'E:\pagefile.sys'
```

When I try to run my app(react), suddently this errors showed up, and even reinstalling the node modules won't work, I tried to reinstall node and webpack too and neither worked.

Comment: Do install npm install async_hooks

Comment: I did and still got the same error

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Its a big project, but I can upload on github if necessary.

Comment: That would be better for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to ask you if you have downloaded the project or you made it thoroughly?
in case you have downloaded (due to the existence of the package.json) at the project directory you can simply:

```
npm i
```

That command will install all the packages expressed in the package.json file with the same version.

if this command hasn't helped you, you can do another thing:

Update the NPM globally using this command:

```
    npm install -g npm@latest
```

*Install another version of "async_hooks". Unfortunately, there is only one version of the package.*

Comment: Also, you can skim through the npm packages to find a similar package in case of need.

Comment: I made it, I am following an youtube tutorial for a project, this error just appeared suddently when my project was just fine, I made it go to a previous version and I still get this error, if I download a project and run it, it will run fine. Also I did the npm install npm thing and still got this

Comment: Just please check your components again. this is likely to happen with VSCODE auto-import functionality. so, it means that when you are writing your code or importing something, the vscode is likely to import something automatically. so please check your files that all the imports are fine and don't represent a wrong path or wrong importing.

Comment: It was really it!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

The problem with 'async_hooks' is that it will only be available in node on serverside - if e.g. webpack tries to create a "universal bundle" performing static bundle analysis - it will fail to find 'async_hooks' on clientside (hence the error).

But: you can circumvent that like so:

```
const async_hooks = eval("typeof window === 'undefined' && require('async_hooks')");
if (async_hooks) { /*.../ }
```

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed the issue by adding the following fallback in the webpack 5 configuration file

```
 resolve: {
  
  fallback: {
   
    async_hooks: false,
  },
}
```

Comment: I added into `webpack.config.js`, but get _Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema_.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by using `<Suspense>` inside a `'use client'` component.

Only use it in server components.