# Weird errors after installing @nuxtjs/auth-next in Nuxt project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxtjs project, after installing @nuxtjs/auth-next and configuring it with config provided below, I have my console suddenly filled with weird errors.

This is my nuxt config:

```
export default { 
   // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head 
   head: { 
     title: 'TikTok clone', 
     htmlAttrs: { 
       lang: 'en', 
     }, 
     meta: [ 
       { charset: 'utf-8' }, 
       { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }, 
       { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Simple TikTok clone' }, 
       { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }, 
     ], 
     link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }], 
   }, 
  
   // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css 
   css: [ 
   ], 
  
   // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins 
   plugins: [], 
  
   // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components 
   components: true, 
  
   // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules 
   buildModules: [ 
     // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript 
     '@nuxt/typescript-build', 
     // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss 
     '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', 
     // https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-fonts-module#readme 
     '@nuxtjs/google-fonts', 
     // https://github.com/nuxt-community/fontawesome-module#readme 
     '@nuxtjs/fontawesome', 
   ], 
  
   // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules 
   modules: [ 
     // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios 
     '@nuxtjs/axios', 
     '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
   ], 
  
   // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios 
   axios: { 
     // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308 
     baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/', 
     credentials: true 
   }, 
  
   // Google fonts module configuration https://google-fonts.nuxtjs.org/options 
   googleFonts: { 
     prefetch: true, 
     families: { 
       Poppins: true, 
     } 
   }, 
  
   // Use custom Tailwind config file 
   tailwindcss: { 
     config: { 
       content: [ 
         `components/**/*.{vue,js}`,  
         `layouts/**/*.vue`,  
         `pages/**/*.vue`,  
         `composables/**/*.{js,ts}`,  
         `plugins/**/*.{js,ts}`,  
         `App.{js,ts,vue}`,  
         `app.{js,ts,vue}` 
       ], 
       theme: { 
         fontFamily: { 
           poppins: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'], 
         }, 
         extend: {}, 
       }, 
       plugins: [], 
     } 
   }, 
  
   // Fontawesome icon configuration 
   fontawesome: { 
     component: "fa", 
     icons: { 
       solid: true, 
       brands: true 
     } 
   }, 
  
   // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build 
   build: { 
   }, 
 }
```

There are these errors:

```
WARN  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                           friendly-errors 19:44:07  


 WARN  in ./node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/on-finished/index.js                    friendly-errors 19:44:07  

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\jakub\Projects\tiktok-clone-30days\client\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\on-finished'
                                                                                          friendly-errors 19:44:07  

 WARN  in ./node_modules/raw-body/index.js                                                friendly-errors 19:44:07  

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\jakub\Projects\tiktok-clone-30days\client\node_modules\raw-body'
                                                                                          friendly-errors 19:44:07  

 WARN  in ./node_modules/hasha/index.js                                                   friendly-errors 19:44:07  

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in 'C:\Users\jakub\Projects\tiktok-clone-30days\client\node_modules\hasha'
                                                                                          friendly-errors 19:44:07  

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                   friendly-errors 19:44:07  

This dependency was not found:                                                            friendly-errors 19:44:07  
                                                                                          friendly-errors 19:44:07  
* fs in ./node_modules/@nuxtjs/auth-next/dist/module.js, ./node_modules/destroy/index.js and 1 other
                                                                                          friendly-errors 19:44:07  
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs                                         friendly-errors 19:44:07  
i Waiting for file changes                                                                                19:44:07  
i Memory usage: 853 MB (RSS: 1.23 GB)                                                                     19:44:07  
i Listening on: http://localhost:3000/                                                                    19:44:07  
No issues found.                                                                                          19:44:07  

 WARN  Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'     19:44:07
```

Installing FS using npm or some other package manager won't work. That error looks like it is some dependency problem but I can't solve it.

Comment: Maybe try that one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71484777/8816585 Otherwise, try to reinstall everything (node_modules reset) + another nuxt-auth version.

Comment: What version of nuxt? the nuxt-auth module is not compatible with nuxt 3.

Comment: @dmarr the "Memory usage" in the shell shows that it's using Nuxt2.