# 'async_hooks' cant be found

Tags: javascript, express, babeljs, browserify

I'm trying to bundle my js file with **browserify** and **babel**: `browserify ./src/background.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify`

The full error message I get is: `Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\prog\html\extvone\async_hooks' required by D:\prog\html\extvone\node_modules\on-finished\index.js`

When I looked into `on-finished\index.js` I saw there was a require for `require('async_hooks')`, but async_hooks didn't lead to a .js file, or anything.

I tried installing all the packages to the same version with `npm i` and update NPM globally as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71485341/20143298), and also intalling `async_hooks` with npm install.

**Edit**:

background.js first lines:

```
import PythonShell from 'python-shell'; 

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

package.json includes:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "python-shell": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0"
  }
```

Versions are the following: Node -> `18.12.1 LTS` 'express' -> `4.18.2`

The 'express' module is the root of the problem. Without it - everything works smoothly.

### Update:

As mentioned in the comments, I tried to use a node-only nodule in the browser. What I actually did is deleted all the dependency on it. In a more general note, I started using VITE instead of Browserify.

Comment: Your node version is probably too old.

Comment: @morganney Unfortunately it is not the case. The error persists with 18.12.1 LTS version and also with 19.2.0.

Comment: Please [put those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask), including which versions of dependencies and tools you're using, and please also show your [mcve].

Comment: `trying to bundle my js file with browserify` - this is your bug. The reason browserify cannot compile it is because `async_hooks` is a node-only (server only) module which means that `on-finished` is also a node-only module that cannot be used in the browser. The fix is simple but can be painful depending on how much you have coded: remove the `on-finished` module from your project and rewrite your code

Comment: @slebetman Thanks! it worked. But do I have to do it everytime im working with express and browserify?