# Can't resolve 'async_hooks'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack

```
./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/on-finished/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'E:\Social_Media\Frontend\app\node_modules\on-finished'

./node_modules/raw-body/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'E:\Social_Media\Frontend\app\node_modules\raw-body'
```

When I try to run my app(react), suddently this errors showed up, and even reinstalling the node modules won't work.re

Comment: Check this answer [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484777/module-not-found-cant-resolve-async-hooks)